# How to implement a Custom Repository using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a Custom Repository using Spring Data but got the following exception:

*Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property {name} found for type {Entity}*

Looks like the *@NoRepositoryBean* is not working proper and Spring is scanning the interfaces that are annotated with it, does anyone knows how to do it in the right way please?

Custom method for all repositories.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    List<T> findAll(Company company);

    EntityManager getEntityManager();
}

public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public List<T> findAll(Company company) {
        //Search by company
    }
}
```

I also have a few repositories that have custom methods, for instance:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface QuestionCustomRepository {
    List<Question> findAllQuestionByTypeAndAsset(Integer[] assetIds);
}

public interface QuestionRepository extends BaseRepository<Question, Integer>, QuestionCustomRepository {
}

@Repository
public class QuestionCustomRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepositoryImpl<Question, Integer> implements QuestionCustomRepository {
    public QuestionCustomRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<Question, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Question> findAllQuestionByTypeAndAsset(Integer[] assetIds) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    // Call Native Query
    }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBaseTest.SpringConfiguration.class, properties = "logging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG")
@DataJpaTest
public class SpringBaseTest {
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EntityScan(basePackageClasses = Question.class)
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = QuestionRepository.class, repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class)
    public static class SpringConfiguration {
    }
}

class QuestionRepository extends SpringBaseTest {
    @Inject
    QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindAllByAssetIts() throws Exception {
        List<Question> list = questionRepository.findAllQuestionByTypeAndAsset(new Integer[]{1,2,3});

        assertThat(list).hasSize(3);
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: I don't know very much about Spring Data - but, In your second example, don't you want to put that @NoRepositoryBean on your second interface QueryRepository?

Comment: Focus on `No property {name} found for type {Entity}`. Maybe your `Question` entity ref a `Entity` entity, and `Entity` has no `name` property. Beyond that I think your code inheritance too much. Can be simplify to `public class QuestionCustomRepositoryImpl implements QuestionCustomRepository` and just inject `EntityManager ` bean. No need to `extends BaseRepositoryImpl`. Also don't mix use `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest`, just use `@DataJpaTest`.

Comment: Hi @RJ.Hwang applied the changes as you suggested but still getting the same error, that message `No property {method_name} found for Type` is random and `method_name` cames from the custom interface, that's why I think is something wrong with `@NoRepositoryBean`.

Comment: The full exception is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.package.product.repository.{EntityName}Repository.{methodName(parameters)}! No property {methodName} found for type {Entity}!` thanks for your help

Comment: Also try remove `@NoRepositoryBean` on `QuestionCustomRepository` interface , because it is only usefull for your `BaseRepository` interface.

Comment: HI @RJ.Hwang you are absolutely right the problem was solved removing `@NoRepositoryBean` from the interfaces, for tests also need to remove `@SpringBootTest` because didn't work proper with `@DataJpaTest`, thanks for that appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved removing `@NoRepositoryBean` from the interfaces and leave just for the `BaseRepository`.

Also need to remove `@SpringBootTest` because was using `@DataJpaTest` already.